# ios - Split a view and animate each part independently

Tags: ios, uiview, split, calayer

I'm looking for splitting a view into multiple strips then animate each strip independently  like moving them from left to right until they go offscreen, with a little delay between each animation.

Do methods exist to split a view or a layer into subviews/sublayers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard method.

You should start off with code to generate an image from the view. Then, instead of a single image draw each half into separate images. Now you can use these 2 images for your animations.

[this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661291/split-uiimage-in-half).

Comment: This is what i tried in first place actually but once you get your multiple images, how can i replace my actual view layer by sub layers containing these images ? Should i just hide the view and programmaticaly add mutiple `UIImageView`s over it and then animate these `UIImageView`s ?

Comment: Exactly yes, animate image views.