# Combining 2 images, working but stretching

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview

I have a square imageview and if the user decides to add another image, it goes into that same image view on the right. So the left half of the imageview is image 1 and the right half is image 2. The only problem with my code is that it squeezes both images into the imageview.

```
@IBAction func secondactiontakepicture(sender: AnyObject) {
    ImagePickerManager.sharedManager.presentImagePicker(self) { (image, source) -> () in
    self.revertimageview2.image = image
        var size = CGSize(width: self.singlefirstimagepostview.frame.width, height: self.singlefirstimagepostview.frame.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        let areaSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width/2, height: size.height)
        self.revertimageview.image!.drawInRect(areaSize)
        let areaSize2 = CGRect(x: size.width/2, y: 0, width: size.width/2, height: size.height)
        self.revertimageview2.image!.drawInRect(areaSize2, blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 1)
        var newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.singlefirstimagepostview.image = newImage
    }

}
```

How do I make it so it show the center portion of image1 on the left and the center portion of image 2 on the right?

[image: combining these 2 images]

[image: currently it is like this]

[image: what I want]

So as an example image 1 are the 2 images i am combining. image 2 is how it is currently (both images squished). image 3 is how I want it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out.

```
        var size = CGSize(width: self.singlefirstimagepostview.frame.width, height: self.singlefirstimagepostview.frame.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        let areaSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width/2, height: size.height)


        var leftimage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.revertimageview.image!.CGImage, CGRectMake(self.revertimageview.image!.size.width*0.25, 0, self.revertimageview.image!.size.width/2 , self.revertimageview.image!.size.height))

        var rightimage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.revertimageview2.image!.CGImage, CGRectMake(self.revertimageview2.image!.size.width*0.25, 0, self.revertimageview2.image!.size.width/2 , self.revertimageview2.image!.size.height))


        let leftyimage = UIImage(CGImage: leftimage)
        let rightyimage = UIImage(CGImage: rightimage)


        //self.revertimageview.image!.drawInRect(areaSize)
        leftyimage!.drawInRect(areaSize)



        let areaSize2 = CGRect(x: size.width/2, y: 0, width: size.width/2, height: size.height)

        //self.revertimageview2.image!.drawInRect(areaSize2, blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 1)

        rightyimage!.drawInRect(areaSize2, blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 1)

        var newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.singlefirstimagepostview.image = newImage
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking into your question I stumbled upon this old blog post where someone wrote up a category for this kind of operations.

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.nl/2010/11/drawing-part-of-uiimage.html

I quickly written a UIImage extension based on that post.

```
extension UIImage {    
  func drawInRect(drawRect: CGRect, fromRect: CGRect, blendMode: CGBlendMode, alpha: CGFloat) {
    if let imageToDraw = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, fromRect){
        var targetRect = drawRect

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, blendMode)
        CGContextSetAlpha(context, alpha)
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, drawRect.origin.y + fromRect.size.height)
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1)
        targetRect.origin.y = 0

        CGContextDrawImage(context, targetRect, imageToDraw)
        CGContextRestoreGState(context)
    }
  }
}
```

Which you could use like below, which takes care of scaling for retina devices as well. In this example I just switched both half of the same image, but you could use the same extension for creating cropped parts of multiple images ofcourse.

```
    let image = UIImage(named: "my_image")!
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height))
    let size = CGSizeMake(image.size.width * image.scale, image.size.height * image.scale)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, image.scale)

    // Draws second half of image in first half
    image.drawInRect(
        CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width / 2, size.height),
        fromRect: CGRectMake(size.width / 2, 0, size.width / 2, size.height),
        blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal,
        alpha: 1)

    // Draws first half of image in second half
    image.drawInRect(
        CGRectMake(size.width / 2, 0, size.width / 2, size.height),
        fromRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width / 2, size.height),
        blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal,
        alpha: 1)

    var newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    imageView.image = newImage
```

Comment: in the code under "// Draws second half of image in first half" I'm getting cannot invoke 'drawinRect with an arguement list type....., and its coming from "fromRect: CGRectMake(size.width / 2, 0, size.width / 2, size.height),". no error when i take that out, but it still squeezes the image without it

Comment: Did you include the extension somewhere in your class or in a seperate class that you added to your target? Because I get the same error if I leave the extension out, but otherwise it should recognize a method on UIImage that accepts those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need split your image first & combine it back. Below is the code for splitting image that i found from other question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28516817/3178993